# Influence of gravity upon gases

Tags: atomic-physics, geophysics

Are gases influenced by gravity?
If yes: so how you can demonstrate that?
Is there are a difference in distribution of gases in the air? So CO2 will be close to surface more than O2?
Si no: why ?
(I know that the gravity even excite will not be important but .. I want to know !)

Comment: Have you heard of [atmospheric pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure)?

Comment: CO2 will not sink to the surface of the earth because there is a lot of sun driven convection that keeps the lower atmosphere mixed.

Comment: @AaronStevens And on that note, look into how the pressure varies with height in the presence of said gravity.

Comment: I know that all the air is influenced by gravity but I was need an affirmation that there are a difference between the attraction upon different molecules of air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “Are gases influenced by gravity? If yes: so how you can demonstrate
>   that?”

The pressure of the atmosphere is greatest at the surface of the earth. This is due to weight of the air above the surface bearing down on the air near the surface. That weight is, of course, due to gravity. That shows the collective influence of gravity on gases.

> “Is there are a difference in distribution of gases in the air? So CO2
>   will be close to surface more than O2? Si no: why ?”

Our atmosphere is a mixture of gases mainly nitrogen and oxygen but also carbon dioxide and others. It’s my understanding that carbon dioxide is well mixed with the other constituents of air at the surface of the earth and is about 400 ppm. Even though carbon dioxide is heavier than oxygen gas which is heavier than nitrogen gas they don’t separate from each other at the ground according to their molecular weights. This is because gases are highly miscible with one another at ordinary temperatures and pressure due to convective currents resulting from heating by the sun.

Hope this helps

Comment: I know that all the air is influenced by gravity but I was need an affirmation that there are a difference between the attraction upon different molecules of air. I think you answered me.

Comment: @user16752 Another way of thinking about it is that the convective air current forces that keep the gas molecules mixed up are far greater than the minuscule downward force that gravity exerts on any one individual gas molecule. I can add this to the answer if you think it would improve the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

All matter, including gasses, are influenced by gravity. It is proven by the fact that we have air to breathe. If the air were not held to the Earth by gravity, then it would dissipate into space. Another proof is that helium weighs less than air, so balloons may float. As we move higher above sea level, such as on top of a mountain, the air becomes thinner (less air pressure), because there is less air above us pressing down because of gravity. Even though some gasses in our atmosphere are heavier than others they stay pretty well mixed together because the sun heats the ground, making the air close to it warm. The warm air rises up and outwards, and helps keep the gasses in the air mixed.